# jQuery validate and custom id's

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i am using jquery validate, and when i am validating like this

```
$("#form").validate({
            // errorLabelContainer: $("div#error"),
            errorElement: "p",
            errorClass: "form-error",
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }
            }
});
```

everything is working fine, but if i have div id like this "x.child.1.0.t", i must use something like this

```
$("#form").validate({
            // errorLabelContainer: $("div#error"),
            errorElement: "p",
            errorClass: "form-error",
            rules: {
                x.child.1.0.t: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }
            }
});
```

And this is not working, how to be?

Comment: By default, the `.validate()` plugin is looking for the `name` attribute of `input`'s not their `id`.

Comment: You right, this was the main problem, by names everything is working :) While testing i had same id and name, but in production they are different. Thank you

Comment: That's a pretty strange value for either an `id` or `name`. Might be easier on you to use a more common format.

Comment: If that was your _main_ problem, why not accept my answer since I was the first to point that out here in comments and in my answer? I even pointed it out to Ricardo before he added to his. :)  No worries either way, and I'm glad you solved it.

Comment: Ah sorry, thought Ricardo was first, no problems, marked you now :) Maybe you know how to add rule by wildcard? When i have "x.child.1.0.t", "x.child.2.0.s", "x.child.1.0.z"?

Comment: Post another question about that... perhaps using `addRule` with a "wildcard"-like jQuery selector it could be done.  If you post another question with all the details about what you're trying to achieve, maybe there's another way.  You can also apply rules with a `class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...but if i have div id like this `x.child.1.0.t`... is not working ...

You must do two things...

- use the `name` attribute of your `input`, rather than `id`.  By default, the `.validate()` plugin is looking for the `name` attribute of `input`'s, not their `id`.  [See docs, under `rules:` item.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)
- put the name inside quotes within your `.validate()` options.  [See docs regarding complex naming.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29)

**HTML:**

```
<input name="x.child.1.0.t" />
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("form").validate({
    // errorLabelContainer: $("div#error"),
    errorElement: "p",
    errorClass: "form-error",
    rules: {
        'x.child.1.0.t': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    }
});​
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c6xKq/)

Answer (score 4):

Put it inside `"` or `'`, like a `string` and don't forgot to use `name` attr.

```
$("#form").validate({
            // errorLabelContainer: $("div#error"),
            errorElement: "p",
            errorClass: "form-error",
            rules: {
                'x.child.1.0.t': {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                }
            }
});
```

`A validation rule associates an element with a validation method, like "validate input with name "primary-mail" with methods "required" and "email".`
[reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

**Fields with complex names (brackets, dots)**

`If your form consists of fields using names that aren't legal JavaScript identifiers, you have to quote those names when using the rules option:` 
[reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29)

Comment: @WesleyMurch, however, it's looking for the `name` attribute and the jsFiddle breaks without it.  http://jsfiddle.net/eyKW9/1/

Comment: @Sparky Yes, maybe OP is doing it.

Comment: The OP specifically said, _"...but if i have div **id** like this..."_

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate by `id` rather than `name` you have to do something like this:

```
$("form").validate({
    errorElement: "p",
    errorClass: "form-error"
});

// This part is ugly because of your strange id
$("#x\\.child\\.1\\.0\\.t").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eyKW9/3/

The reason for the backslashes is that you have to escape the `.` characters or else jQuery/Sizzle thinks it's a class selector.

In general it's better to avoid `id` values like this, because you will run into issues with javascript and css. Stick to alphanum dash and underscore if possible.